# Chrome boxshadow and border conflicting

Tags: html, css

I seem to be having an issue with Chrome and not FF or IE. If I have a div

```
<div id = "someDiv">
  <input name = "row1" type = "radio" value = "Y">Y
  <input name = "row1" type = "radio" value = "N">N
  <div id = "hiddenRow1"></div>
  <div id = "hiddenRow2"></div>
</div>
```

And CSS like this

```
#someDiv {
width: 600px;
padding-top: 3%;
background-color: rgba(24, 25, 27, 0.98);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.28);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.28);
box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.28);
border: 1px solid #8D3232;
}

.hiddenRow1, .hiddenRow2 {
  display:none;
}
```

And we do some jquery like this

```
$('input[name="row1"]').on('change', function(){
        var yesno = $(this).val();
        if (yesno == "Y"){
            $('#hiddenRow1').slideDown(500);
            $('#hiddenRow2').slideUp(500);
        }else{
            $('#hiddenRow1').slideUp(500);
            $('#hiddenRow2').slideDown(500);

        }
    });
```

I am getting this really annoying bug where when a hidden row slides down and extends the height of its parent div, the parent's div original border remains on screen until the window is resized or any CSS effect is altered (basically the page is some how re-rendered).

The only way I can solve this is buy removing the main div's box shadow, but I don't want to break the style of the website. I cannot reproduce this on jsfiddle but I do have a screenshot.

Any ideas?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FG7tz.png

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, I made another div that contains the first hidden row. I gave it a background that was the size and colour of the background div. That way it just overlapped the buggy border.